# Correct headline in scientific pro/contra table

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, british-english, writing

Which words are appropriate for the headline in a table with pros and cons in a scientific paper (physics)?

```
      PROS        CONS
ice   cheap       cold
fish  expensive   warm
```

Comment: For/Against; Advantage/Disadvantage. A little more context would be helpful: what are you actually discussing?

Comment: Depends **entirely** on context: Is it a paper in ichthyology? in cryogenics? in statistical research? And more...

Comment: Benefits and drawbacks?  Please give more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terms you suggest (pro and con) are generally associated with spoken presentation or informal writing. "Advantages" and "Disadvantages" would be appropriate for a more formal paper. "Strengths" and "Weaknesses" could also be used.